# How can I access venue images in the Here API

Tags: here-api

The Here.com developer pricing says they include venue images in the demo pricing tier. I don't see any reference to any of those images in the "here" and "search" API endpoints.

Is there an additional parameter i need to pass besides the ones being passed here?

`https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?
    at=30.269446%2C-97.741067
    q=chipotle
    size=10
    tf=plain
    app_id=XXXXXXXXXXXX
    app_code=XXXXXXXXXXXX`

Answer (score 0):

I think Venue Images refers to the Venue Maps image tiles (https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/venue-maps/topics/quick-start.html). So you can overlay venue maps on the map. If you also need to interact with venue maps, then you need Venue Models (the JSON part of the Venue Maps API).
It is not related to the Places API.